# menu background colour not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

my css3 menu doesn't seem to show the red background. i can't figure out why.

```
#nav{
background-color:red;
height:40px;
width: 550px;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 20px;
}
ul li{
color:silver;
}
```

for the css, and here's my code

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Seneda</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1>Create Your Account</h1>
```

i can't figure out what I'm missing to make it work

Answer (score 3):

You haven't set the #nav anywhere in your HTML code.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Seneda</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1>Create Your Account</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<div class="menu">
   <div id="nav">
    <ul>
       <li>Seneda</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
  <h1>Create Your Account</h1>
```

Demo **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a65oe7at/)**